# Attempt to return Range; Run Time Error 91

Tags: excel, vba, range

I wrote a function that's simply supposed to return a range. However I get a run time error 91 (object variable or with block not set). I don't understand why, since the debugger says, that the value is set and Nothing at the same time.

The idead behind this code is the following:
I've got a userform where the user can select up to 6 columns, column A is always included and therefore not optional. I would like to return the range of that selection.

[screenshot, debugger values at bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fc2G.png)

```
Private Function calcGraphRange() As range
    Dim rng0, rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6 As range

    Debug.Assert (Me.CheckBox1.Value = True)

    Set rng0 = range("A:A") 
    Set rng1 = range("B:B") 
    Set rng2 = range("C:C") 
    Set rng3 = range("D:D") 
    Set rng4 = range("E:E") 
    Set rng5 = range("F:F") 
    Set rng6 = range("G:G") 


    Set calcGraphRange = Application.Union(rng0, _
    IIf(Me.CheckBox1.Value = True, rng1, rng0), _
    IIf(Me.CheckBox2.Value = True, rng2, rng0), _
    IIf(Me.CheckBox3.Value = True, rng3, rng0), _
    IIf(Me.CheckBox4.Value = True, rng4, rng0), _
    IIf(Me.CheckBox5.Value = True, rng5, rng0), _
    IIf(Me.CheckBox6.Value = True, rng6, rng0))
End Function
```

Here is what I did so far:

- Made sure all objects are set ([Can a VBA function in Excel return a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439510/can-a-vba-function-in-excel-return-a-range))
- Made sure the checkboxes are accessible
- Made sure the IIf syntaxt works like I'm attempting to use it

I'd appreciate any help or tips. Have a nice day.

Comment: What does 'Me' refer to in your code. i.e. is your function inside a class?

Comment: Hi and thank you for your comment. So the debugger shows, that "Me" represents the UserForm_Main (the one that holds the checkboxes). The code is written in the general codebehind of my userform. This function is not inside of a class or another function. I hope that helps.

Comment: I tried it with a userform, the code works for me, have you tested to set the private to public? Are the checkbox names correct? What are you doing with the result of the function? I called it by using msgbox(calcGraphRange().address) and i received the address of the range.

Comment: I think the problem may be in the code that's calling this function.  As @Andreas said - the code runs as it is. `rng0` - `rng5` are declared as variants though, only `rng6` is a range.  `Dim rng0 as Range, rng1 as Range, ....`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So I tried changing the access modifier, which didn't change anything. All the checkbox names were correct. However changing the caller function worked for me aswell. I have 6 checkboxes and a button. That button is supposed to get the range and pass that range, so a diagram can be created. I guess storing the Range as: Dim rr As Range </b> rr = calcGraphRange is creating the problem.

Comment: Always best to *qualify* which worksheet each `Range` is on.